# Is this a bad use of GC.ReRegisterForFinalize()

Tags: c#, performance, garbage-collection

So I've heard that GC.ReRegisterForFinalize() should generally be avoided, but I see no reason to not use it for my specific problem. So first this is a very performance sensitive area of code so speed counts.

I have a stack of unmanaged resources and small (8 byte) managed objects each of which wrap one of these unmanaged resources. When a wrapper is created it pushes an unmanaged resource on the stack and wraps it. When its destructed instead of removing its resource from the middle of the stack (which would cause the whole stack to shift) it can do one of two things: either it can push an int representing its stack position into a queue, so the next object created can wrap that stack position instead of pushing a new one, or it can push itself into a queue and reregister for finalize and be reused.

The difference may be small, I realize I may be splitting hairs, but atleast with the second method I'm saving an allocation and deallocation each time it happens. So whats the downside?

Comment: Are you sure that the logic you're using actually increases performance?

Comment: @thecoop Not entirely sure. It seems like it would. I'm still hammering out some bugs. Might be a while before I can do real performance testing. Just wondering if there's a reason I should avoid this route.

Comment: If you're planning to reuse the objects, why are you finalizing them in the first place? Figure out a strategy (ideally using real performance data) and stick with it. If you're re-registering for finalization as part of your normal processes, you're probably doing something wrong. In any case - profile.

Comment: @Luaan becuase I want the wrappers to be valid for as long as they're being used without having to explicitly call some Dispose function. Letting the garbage handler determine when they're ready to recycle seems like the smartest route.

Comment: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*. See what the performance is like with normal code, then, and only then, test if there is a significant difference with this logic. If there is, then put this in with LOTS of comments explaining what's going on and why you're doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let me just write this down as an answer.

`GC.ReRegisterForFinalize` has a two uses - to revert the `GC.SuppressFinalize()` method, and to "resurrect" an object that's already in it's finalizer (the `~SomeType` method).

You just need to understand how finalization works. The basic idea is, that a managed object that holds some unmanaged resource will get an opportunity to release the unmanaged resource when it's collected by the garbage collector. Since in most cases, you wan to release the resources much earlier (e.g. releasing a `SqlConnection` to make sure we're not keeping unnecessary sockets open), an optimization has been introduced, which is part of the "disposable pattern".

So, the finalizer will contain the code to get rid of the unmanaged resource, and nothing else. To handle the early disposal, we're going to implement a `Dispose` method, which does some cleaning-up, including releasing the unmanaged resource. Now, the type does have a finalizer, so it is registered for finalization by default - however, we've already released those unmanaged resources before, so there's no point in getting finalized on collection. So you call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`, which basically removes this instance from the list of items to finalize on collection.

However, what if your class is not just a simple wrapper around the unmanaged resource, but for example allows you to release and reacquire it again? `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize` comes to the rescue - whenever you reacquire the unmanaged resource, you'll register yourself for finalization again, to ensure proper cleanup.

This somewhat violates a simple principle in dealing with unamanged resources in .NET, which is basically that the managed wrapper should be as small and simple as possible. So your real class that does some real work would use this tiny wrapper instead of directly using the unmanaged resource. This is one reason why you really don't need `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize`, and why seeing it in code might look fishy.

The second use for `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize` however, gets even more objectionable. It allows you to stop the finalization of the instance, and bring it back to life. Doesn't sound too bad? Well, for one, it shows that your design is likely flawed. More importantly, though, all the other instances that were only referenced by this instance (e.g. a field pointing to another .NET object) might have already been collected. This is a great way to introduce bugs that are very hard to reproduce. Programmers don't like those much, so you're mostly trying to avoid those as much as possible.

So, TL;DR version: You probably don't need `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize`. If you keep the managed wrapper in a list of "unused" objects, it will not be collected, and thus it will not be finalized either. It would only make a difference if you released the unmanaged resource first (in `Dispose` including a call to `GC.SuppressFinalize`), and then wanted to create a new unmanaged resource for the same managed instance. Which probably isn't what you want (there really isn't much of a point).